# Optaplanner 6.3.0 Variablelistener corruption

Tags: optaplanner

When running the TW-VRP example test "solveModel_cvrptw_100customers_AFastAssert" in the examples section on env mode FULL_ASSERT, then the following illegal state is shown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: VariableListener corruption: the entity (TimeWindowedCustomer-1)'s shadow variable (TimeWindowedCustomer.arrivalTime)'s corrupted value (null) changed to uncorrupted value (161000) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
>   Probably the VariableListener class for that shadow variable (TimeWindowedCustomer.arrivalTime) forgot to update it when one of its sources changed after completedAction (Initial score calculated).

at org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.app.VehicleRoutingPerformanceTest.solveModel_cvrptw_100customers_AFastAssert(VehicleRoutingPerformanceTest.java:64)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"corrupted value (null) changed to uncorrupted value (161000)"

Looks like `null`'s aren't propagated correctly in your custom VariableListener. It's probably due a bug in the example that has been fixed in PLANNER-500 and [this commit](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/commit/626a673cd3a3522378d9fc8658775817eb2e1f11).